# Embedded NoSQL DB for .NET Core

Tags: .net, .net-core, nosql

What would be the best choice for an embedded NoSQL DB which could be used from the .NET Core application (could be built to run in Linux)?

So in summary, requirements:

1. Can be used in the .NET Core application (ASP.NET 5 MVC), and compiled to run in Linux.
2. NoSQL, document-based.
3. Embedded, does not require server installation, can be deployed together with an application.

Comment: Option A) use Sqlite with one table with two columns.

Comment: Option B) https://github.com/iboxdb

Comment: There is [DBreeze](https://dbreeze.codeplex.com) (not a document store  though) which has .NET Core support, and also [LiteDB](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB) which should run fine for a UWP app (counts as .NET Core?). The thing is .NET Core is brand new and adopters are only slowly picking up. I am sure RavenDB and RaptorDB have .NET Core support on their roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

Berkeley DB for .NET and .NET Core is available at https://nuget.endpointsystems.com . My company (Endpoint Systems) is an Oracle gold partner and resells licenses for Berkeley DB and Berkeley DB XML on their behalf.